# How to use xvfb to run my automated rspec-capybara chromedriver tests?

Tags: capybara, rspec, xvfb

I read through [this](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml#heading6)  and I don't quite get it.  If I currently run my rspec capybara tests using chromedriver, how will I change that to xvfb ?

I see the examples like `Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x32` but I'm not sure how to integrate that into my actual UI feature specs.

Comment: try looking into how it is done in [docker-chromium-xvfb](https://github.com/mark-adams/docker-chromium-xvfb)

Answer (score 1):

This link explains Firefox browser testing with Capybara: Hope the below link give you an insight of the approach. http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless

Installing xvfb: Example command : For Debian based systems:

apt-get install xvfb

Redhat based systems: yum install xorg-X11-server-Xvfb

Run the script: xvfb-run ruby headless.rb

Executing the script:

Option 1
Start Xvfb on a specific display port and background the process
Tell the terminal session to use the display port
Run the test
Xvfb :99 &
export DISPLAY=:99
ruby headless.rb

Option 2
Simply type the below command
xvfb-run ruby headless.rb

Option 3

Install the headless gem
Update the test setup and teardown to use it
Run the test

Comment: Thanks!  the link may go back in the future.  Could you post the essential info in case that happens so that future readers still know what you are saying? @Bhavani

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Updated the answer with the steps.

Comment: Nice +1 To accept...  Can one replace firefox with chromedriver ?

Comment: Replaced Firefox with Chromedriver.